# ZK Framework wired Textbox return NullPointerException when I call a @Listen onClick

Tags: java, model-view-controller, zk, zul

I'm new to ZK Framework and I'm excercising with a simple login form. I gather username/email and password when the user click the button.

When I test the login button a NullPointerException occurs. I can't figure out what is wrong with the code. Can you help me?

Let's see the app files!

#### **View: login.zul**

```
<?page title="Login" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"?>
<zk>
    <window title="Login" border="normal" apply="zk_auth.controller.LoginController">
        <vlayout>
                Email: <textbox id="EmailBox" type="email" constraint="no empty" />
                Password: <textbox id="PasswordBox" type="password" constraint="no empty" />
        </vlayout>
            <button id="LoginButton" label="Login"/>
    </window>
</zk>
```

#### **Controller: LoginController.java**

```
package zk_auth.controller;

/*Omitted imports for brevity.*/

public class LoginController extends SelectorComposer<Component>
{
    @Wire("LoginButton")
    private Button LoginButton;

    @Wire
    private Textbox EmailBox;

    @Wire
    private Textbox PasswordBox;

    @Listen("onClick = button#LoginButton")
    public void Login()
    {
        UserCredential User = new UserCredential(EmailBox.getValue(), PasswordBox.getValue());
        Authentication Authenticator = new Authentication();
        if(Authenticator.checkUserCredential(User))
            Messagebox.show("Authenticated!");
        else
            Messagebox.show("Access denied!");
    }
}
```

Now, when I click the login button, a NullPointerException occurs, showing
[this popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anZbm.png).

#### **Console log**

```
dic 06, 2018 10:17:26 AM org.zkoss.util.resource.ResourceCache$Info isValid
INFORMAZIONI: Source is changed: /login.zul
dic 06, 2018 10:17:35 AM org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl handleError
GRAVE: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at zk_auth.controller.LoginController.Login(LoginController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.select.Selectors$ComposerEventListener.onEvent(Selectors.java:686)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.onEvent(AbstractComponent.java:3162)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3132)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.AbstractComponent.service(AbstractComponent.java:3074)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.EventProcessor.process(EventProcessor.java:138)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.processEvent(UiEngineImpl.java:1846)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.process(UiEngineImpl.java:1618)
    at org.zkoss.zk.ui.impl.UiEngineImpl.execUpdate(UiEngineImpl.java:1321)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.process(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:606)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doGet(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:482)
    at org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet.doPost(DHtmlUpdateServlet.java:490)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can't really figure out what is wrong with this code. I only know the exception has been thrown at Login() function.

Comment: Which line is number 35?

Comment: Line number 35 is public void Login()
Anyway, the problem was that the automatic building was not sincronized with change in my code, so removing and readding server in Eclipse or restarting the server make the code work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace your code fragment with using annotation @Listen

```
@Listen("onClick = button#LoginButton")
```

to

```
@Listen("onClick = #LoginButton")
```